# Recursively calling a procedure in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, recursion

i have a table of groups user mapping where we create groups of users and the groups are assigned to other groups. So there is a hierarchy of groups for a user. And from the table i want to know which groups a user can access?

Suppose a user with user id 1 is assigned to a group with  group_id 2 and group with id 2 is assigned to a group with id 3. so ultimately, user can access both groups with id 2 & 3. For this i created two procedure 1 that fetches all the groups which user is assigned directly and other procedure is to get parent groups of these groups recursively.

here is the dump of my sql table

```
`CREATE TABLE `group_user_mapping` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'user/group',
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updation_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `group_user_mapping` (`id`, `group_id`, `type_id`, `type`, `creation_date`, `updation_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'user', '2016-12-06 08:53:19', NULL),
(2, 2, 1, 'group', '2016-12-06 08:53:19', NULL),
(3, 3, 2, 'group', '2016-12-06 12:15:00', '2016-12-06 12:19:21'),
(4, 4, 2, 'group', '2016-12-06 12:16:00', '2016-12-06 12:16:48'),
(5, 5, 1, 'user', '2016-12-06 12:20:05', '2016-12-07 06:37:51');`
```

and my two procedures are ->

this procedure returs the groups to which user is assigned

```
     CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetUsersOfGroup`(IN `user_id` INT)
        NO SQL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE c1 INT;
        DECLARE Flag INT;
        declare gr_id INT;

        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT group_id FROM group_user_mapping WHERE type_id = user_id and type='user';

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempo;
              CREATE TEMPORARY Table tempo (id int);

        OPEN cur;

            ins_loop: LOOP
                FETCH cur INTO c1;
                IF done THEN

                    LEAVE ins_loop;
                END IF;
                set gr_id=c1;
           INSERT into tempo values(gr_id); 
                CALL getAllGroups(gr_id);

            END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur;
        select DISTINCT(id) as group_id from tempo; 
         DROP TEMPORARY TABLE  IF EXISTS tempo;
     END

And the secod procedure is to return parent of groups where recursion is not working

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllGroups`(IN `gid` INT)
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE c2 INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT group_id FROM group_user_mapping WHERE type_id = gid and type='group';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO c2;
            IF done THEN

                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
            set @Flag=c2;
        insert INTO tempo values(@Flag);
        #CALL getAllGroups(@Flag);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
     select id as group_id from tempo; 
 END
```

the result output should be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` .

It seems that it is not working please help me to sort this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The recursion doesn't work because you commented out the recursive call: `#CALL getAllGroups(@Flag);`. Apart from that: there are better ways to build trees in databases, e.g. [nested sets](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Comment: i uncommented ,but still no progress.

Comment: procedure call -  SET @p0='1'; CALL `GetUsersOfGroup`(@p0);

Comment: So what DO you get as a result? Apart from being very inefficient and not loop-safe (=if you have a loop in your tree, it will loop to the recursion limit into an error), it looks correct.

Comment: @Solarflare i am  only getting 1st child not grand-child

Comment: As I said in my first comment: You get only 1st child if you don't remove the `#` from `#CALL getAllGroups(@Flag);`. If you remove it, it will give you every row. So check if you really removed it. But as I also said: using recursion for this is the most inefficient way to go through your tree. Literally every algorithm you can find on stack overflow to retrieve your tree will be faster than your solution. Nevertheless, you code is working.